# How can I tell which VNC package I'm using?

Tags: package-management, vnc

I have a system that someone else set up and I am unable to contact that person any more. I connect to the system both via SSH and a VNC server. I'm trying to replicate the VNC setup exactly on another system (VNC is used by some of our automated testing).

The currently configured system is Fedora, and I am trying to duplicate the setup on an Ubuntu Server system.

My issue is that there are many VNC packages out there, and there are multiple installed on this system. I want to make sure I get the same one.

`dnf list |grep vnc` shows tigervnc, x11vnc, gvnc, gtk-vnc, svncpp and multiple variations on those packages. Killing a vncserver session on this system shows "Killing Xvnc process ID 30174", but that seems generic, as all of these packages are vnc servers for X.

`vncserver -v` and `vncserver --version` are both invalid commands, and `which vncserver` reports "/usr/bin/vncserver" (and it's not a symbolic link), which isn't very helpful.

How can I tell which vncserver program I'm using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If rpm command is supported, You can do

```
rpm -qf /usr/bin/vncserver
```

which shoud list you the vnc package